# How to create a database in MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle from a single ANT build?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, ant

How do I create a database from scratch, creating the tables and populating them with some sample data, in MySQL, SQL Server as well as Oracle using a single ANT build?

Comment: Why close? I have looked for this on google and even on SO and could not find anything which is working at my end.

Comment: The vote is marked as *Not a real question*.  Probably because your question is a bit skimpy.  When you say 'create a database'  do you mean literally create a database from scratch or just build tables, etc

Comment: You can prepare things in sql files and use `<exec>` task to call the command line tools of the DBMSes. We are currently using this method to create databases and build tables in MySQL.

Comment: @APC. I need to create entire db from scratch. Then create tables in it and populate them with some sample data also. Sorry if I was not clear with my question.

Comment: no offense, but since when do java devs control the creation of Oracle databases?  Asking for trouble imo (DBAs don't typically create java apps either ;) I hope this is just playing in dev, not a process to be used in prod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we do with **ant** and **mysql** is like this:

**Prepare a SQL file like this:**

```
drop database if exists test;
create database test character set utf8;
use test;

create table Account_ (
...fields
) engine InnoDB;

create .... more tables ...
```

**Use the ant script like this:**

```
<exec executable="mysql" input="test.sql" />
```

So I think the main problem you have to deal with is to generate sample sql file, not working with Ant.

What we are doing is to write a sample-sql-builder which generates data according to ftl files (which shows the table structures). We just run it from ant, the all the logic is in pure java.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Its not working at my end. I am getting Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysql": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified error.

Comment: That is a path problem, not the ant problem. Check if you can run mysql in your terminal (cmd if you are using Windows). Also you need to know that the mysql command line program may need the DBA's username and password, and you can use nested element `<arg line="" />` in `<exec>` to give mysql parameters.

Comment: Some SQL scripts will be usable for any flavour of DBMS while others will entail product specific syntax.  This means you will need to make up the process into lots of small scripts, which are assigned to Ant targets, and which can be called in various combinations.

Comment: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal Clone the source code and take a look at portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/tools/samplesqlbuilder, it is a example of generating sample sql file with data. The data amount is set in benchmarks.properties in the "benchmarks", and build.xml in this folder is the ant script to use the samplesqlbuilder.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use something like [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org) if you need to manage a multi-DBMS schema definition.

The Liquibase schema definition is DBMS-independent and Liquibase will handle the translation into the various dialects for you. You can still have DBMS specific code in the schema definition though.

Liquibase has an [Ant task](http://liquibase.org/manual/ant) so that you can integrate it into your build script. But as you can basically call any Java program from within Ant, you can use the "normal" commandline mode as well.

Note that "create a database" in the Oracle world usually means a full blown instance creation which is most certainly not what you want (and will certainly not be allowed to do by the DBA)

Comment: You might even be able to create the database as well from liquibase, by combining a custom SQL refactoring with a precondition on the changeset, that it should only execute on a particular DB. (http://www.liquibase.org/manual/custom_sql, http://www.liquibase.org/manual/preconditions)

Answer (score 1):

No one mentioned it but you can also use the ant sql task. Below is an ant macro that I use. The macro depends on a bunch of properties that are read in from a .properties file over the years I have used variants of this macro with Postgres, Oracle, MySQL, DB2, MS SQL Server

```
<macrodef name="oracle-admin">
    <attribute name="sqlfile" />
    <attribute name="onerror" default="continue" />
    <attribute name="autocommit" default="true" />
    <attribute name="expandproperties" default="true" />
    <attribute name="delimitertype" default="normal" />
    <sequential>
        <sql 
            driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
        url="${oracle.url}" 
        userid="${oracle.db.admin.user}" 
        password="${oracle.db.admin.password}" 
        classpath="${oracle.jdbc.jar}" 
        expandproperties="@{expandproperties}"
        keepformat="true"
        delimitertype="@{delimitertype}"
        rdbms="oracle"
        onerror="@{onerror}"  

        print="true"
        autocommit="@{autocommit}">

           <transaction src="@{sqlfile}"> </transaction>
        </sql>
       </sequential>        
    </macrodef>
```

The macro is fed an SQL file, the sql file can contain ant properties which will be replaced by the values from the properties file.

```
CREATE ROLE ${postgres.db.user} 
WITH   
       LOGIN
       PASSWORD '${postgres.db.password}';

CREATE DATABASE ${postgres.db.database}
       OWNER ${postgres.db.user}
       ENCODING='UTF8';
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to maintain different sql scripts and run them from ant using [exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html).  Second option will be to have single meta-information file from which you generate appropriate sql for database and then use exec task.

I agree liquibase will be the most elegant open source solution for you. You may require some [manual steps.](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/custom_sql)

What we do is a little different. We create custom java program than can load sql and make jdbc calls. This works, weakest part will be in parsing the .sql files.   This java program is called from ant task, using [java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)

Database creation - This can be automated - but very tightly coupled to database server. Oracle dbca has command lines. If this is for some kind of internal deployment , say testing?In that case using different schema will be good enough- which can be handled via jdbc.